# Most readable (in code terms) way to fill a map<string, string> with data on construction in C++03

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a `map<string, string>` and I need to fill it with default pairs on construction. like `"Sam" : "good", "ram" : "bad"`. How in C++03 to do it most readably in code terms on construction?

Comment: `map<string, string> mymap; mymap["Sam"] = "good"; mymap["ram"] = "bad";`?

Comment: Can you use boost - they have some nice std::map init stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`boost::assign::map_list_of`](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of) lets you do this with some pretty looking syntax, but if you can't use Boost, you could write your own.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template< class Key, class Type, class Traits = std::less<Key>,
          class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair <const Key, Type> > >
class MapInit
{
  std::map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator> myMap_;

  /* Disallow default construction */
  MapInit();

public:
  typedef MapInit<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator> self_type;
  typedef typename std::map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator>::value_type value_type;

  MapInit( const Key& key, const Type& value )
  {
    myMap_[key] = value;
  }


  self_type& operator()( const Key& key, const Type& value )
  {
    myMap_[key] = value;
    return *this;
  }


  operator std::map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator>()
  {
    return myMap_;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::string> myMap = 
    MapInit<int, std::string>(10, "ten")
                             (20, "twenty")
                             (30, "thirty");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you could do this in C++03 is by doing

`mapName["Key"] = "Value";`

If you have many you could have a function that initializes it.

```
map<std::string,std::string> makeMap() {
   map<std::string,std::string> example;
   example["Sam"] = "good";
   example["Ram"] = "bad";
   return example;
}
```